# Is there a term that covers both wasei eigo and gairaigo?

Tags: loanwords, terminology, wasei-eigo

Is there a term that covers both wasei eigo ("Japanese-made English") and gairaigo (words from foreign languages)? Can you call them カタカナ語?

Comment: 「カタカナ語」とか「横文字」とかですかね・・・？

Comment: @choco Would you consider posting that as an answer? :-)

Answer (score 3):

[Wikipedia「外来語」](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%A4%96%E6%9D%A5%E8%AA%9E)によると、

> 外来語とは、日本語における借用語のうち、漢語とそれ以前の借用語を除いたものである。おもに西洋諸言語からの借用であり、 洋語とも呼ばれる。また、カタカナで表記することが多いことからカタカナ語 、横書きで表記する言葉として日本に入ってきたことから横文字とも呼ばれる。

とあるので、「外来語」は「洋語」「カタカナ語」「横文字」とも呼ばれるようです。「和製英語」もこのように呼ばれるかどうかは書かれていませんが、少なくとも「カタカナ語」「横文字」は、「外来語」「和製英語(または和製外来語)」を指して使われていると思います。

Answer (score 1):

First, *wasei eigo* should be viewed as a subcategory of *eigo-gairaigo*, i.e. *gairaigo* derived from English.

So, the pattern should look as follows

- *wasei eigo* ⊂ *eigo-gairaigo* ⊂ *gairaigo*

*Gairaigo* are words taken from foreign languages in general, and *eigo-gairaigo* are words derived from English; lastly *wasei eigo* is literally English made in Japan (i.e. words created in Japanese resembling English words).

Both *wasei eigo* and *gairaigo* have their specific usages. Maybe you could refer to both of them as "*katakana-eigo*", since both use the katakana script and both are mainly taken from English.
(Check Miller, 1997: 124)

More generally, there is a term called *wasei gairaigo* (Miller, 1997: 127). It is Japanese made from words in other languages (not necessarily only English). For example テーマソング, where テーマ comes from Dutch *Thema* and ソング from English *song*.

Comment: Hello and welcome. I found parts of your post difficult to understand, so I partly rewrote it. You can [edit](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/posts/86010/edit) the post to rollback the changes if I misunderstood anything.

Comment: Thank you for correcting my grammar, and your words are the same as I want to talk about. I am not native English and my grammar is not that good, but I am now doing research about _wasei eigo_ and I have urged to answer this question with all my knowledge about _wasei eigo_ things.